# Is it allowed for a Jew to pray in mosques?

Tags: tefilla, rambam, synagogue, islam

Is it allowed for a Jew to pray in mosques? 
I live in Kuwait so its impossible to find any beith knesseth here; I follow Rambamistic minhaq.

I mean going to a mosque to pray Jewish prayer when i'm far from home, if it's more kosher/properly to pray in mosques than somewhere in parks etc (not right after azan or not when its time to pray for Muslims).

Comment: Personally, I think that you would be better off praying at home. From the way you ask it seems as there would not be a minyan anyways. Based on what I have read about mosques, you would be safer not being seen to pray.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya! Thanks for sharing the question. Consider learning ore about the site from this short beginners' guide: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/3887/8775.

Comment: The idea of praying in a mosque is disputed between the Rambam (permitted) and the Ran ( prohibited) and in our times Chacham Ovadia (permitted) and Tzitz Eliezer ( prohibited). However,I have never seen a posek who allows one to pray with muslims together during their prayer time.